# urllib.request and urlopen input error

Tags: python

I am a new user in python.  I have the following code that should per a professional tutorial that I'm using.  I have python 3.x and fairly certain the use of urllib.request and urlopen is correct so I'm confused as to why this is not working. If someone can explain why this does not work please let help me.  I put the traceback error code below the code snippet.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen("http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt") as story:
    story_words = []
    for line in story:
        line_words = line.decode("utf-8").split()
        for word in line_words:
            story_words.append(word)
```

The error message was as follows:

ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen'

Comment: The error message is missing..

Comment: I got the words...  ['It', 'was', 'the', 'best' ....]there is an indent error when i copied your code..

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import urllib2
story_words = []
url = 'http://sixty-north.com/c/t.txt'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for line in cr:
     for word in line :
         line_words = word.split(' ')
         for word in line_words:
                story_words.append(word)
print story_words
```

Comment: How is this an improvement to OP's code (which BTW is functional)? We don't even know what problem(s) he had... Not to mention that your code should be adapted for Python 3 (what OP uses).

Comment: I apologize.  I was expecting to be notified via my email and assumed no one responded to my question.  That being said the error message was as follows: ImportError: cannot import name 'urlopen'

Comment: @Kevin, have you tried my code? did it give you any error?

Comment: Hello,  unfortunately, it did not work.  I have python 3.4 and I'm not sure if urllib2 is valid for that version.  I ran my original code and appears to work just fine now. The only thing that I did was reinstall python 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to close the loop on my open questions.  I downloaded the python .msi file again and reinstalled.

For whatever reason, the program appears to be working just fine. I honestly do not know why but I wanted to at least say that the matter is closed.

Thanks everyone for you help and consideration.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

Instead of the above code, use this

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
```

Comment: OP clearly stated that he is using Python 3 (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen)).

Comment: Thanks Selva, but can you briefly explain why I cannot use urllib.request?  Is this not allowed for python 3.x?